# BufferedReader readline

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline

I'm trying to use the bufferedReader for just practice, so every time I press enter in the console, it gives me the right answer, but not after one enter hit, I press enter more than once in order to get the result.

my code for the BufferedReader:

```
InputStreamReader irs = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String choose = br.readLine();
```

my if statement for the BufferedReader:

```
if ((choose = br.readLine()).equals("1)) {
            System.out.println("You chose: " + option1);
        } else if ((choose = br.readLine()).equals("2")) {
            System.out.println("You chose: " + option2);
        } else if ((choose = br.readLine()).equals("3")) {
            System.out.println("You chose: " + option3);
        }
```

the result from the console:

```
your choice: 

1

1

You chose: Dog
```

I should enter the choice more than once in order to get the result. 
Any suggestion on how to correct that? 
Thanks!

Comment: You should only read from the reader once. Every call to `readLine()` will advance the stream and might return `null`.

Answer (score 4):

You are reading another line of input each time you call [`readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29).  You already have the input in `choose`; there is no need to call `readLine` every time you have a condition.

Just use

```
if ((choose.equals("1")) {
```

and similarly for the other conditions.

Answer (score 1):

```
choose = br.readLine();
if(choose.equals("1"))
//....
else if(choose.equals("2"))
//....
//and so on
```